Expose local kubernetes function to my pc
So I have a function running in my kubernetes cluster.
NAME            BUILDSTATE   SERVINGSTATE   BUILDER         SERVING         ADDRESS                                           AGE
minio-event     Succeeded    Running        builder-bthqn   serving-br7lv   http://minio-event.default.svc.cluster.local/     3d1h
python-sample   Succeeded    Running        builder-l9rbt   serving-5t5cr   http://python-sample.default.svc.cluster.local/   3d21h

But this url is not accessible from my pc. How can i expose this url so its accessible on my pc (localhost for example). I know the function is working because I can curl it inside the kubernetes cluster.
All help is greatly appreciated!
Edit
Im using openfunctions as serverless functions framework on kubernetes
https://openfunction.dev/

What resource type exactly are you using? I don't believe Kubernetes has native support for "serverless" functions, which means you typically need a framework of some sort (like knative, openfaas, etc). Which one you're using will influence potential answers.

Thanks for comment, i edited the question!
